# ConverFrom-JSON: Invalid JSON Primitive DOT

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable

So what I'm trying is to get the id which is in the JSON under value. I'm running:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authToken -Method Get
```

And getting:

```
@odata.context                                      value
--------------                                      -----
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata          {@{id=09eef6d9-6e66-4676-8d0f-c66e3174d5ea; ...}}
#deviceManagement/depOnboardingSettings
```

The output I'm trying to achive simply is `$enrollId = 09eef6d9-6e66-4676-8d0f-c66e3174d5ea`.

I tried to use `| Out-String` and `| ConvertFrom-Json` but the error message persists:

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON-Primitiv: .
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. It was a http response.

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/depOnboardingSettings"
$enrollTokenId = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authToken -Method Get
$enrollTokenId = ($enrollTokenId.value).id


PS C:\PS-azure\imports> $enrollTokenId
09eef6d9-6e66-4676-8d0f-c66e3174d5ea
```